# How to update a Foreign Key value in Flask Sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

```
class VehicleModel(db.Model):
__tablenam__ = 'vehicle'
id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)


class DriverModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'driver'
id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
v_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('vehicle.id'))
v_rel = db.relationship('VehicleModel',backref=db.backref('vehicle',uselist=False))


def update(self,id,v_id):
    self.id = id
    self.v_id = v_id
    db.session.commit()
```

In this above code, i am not able to update the value of v_id. Sqlalchemy is not throwing any sql error either. I don't know, the update method is working fine but not able to update v_id value. The value of v_id remains same as it was set when adding the column for first time.

Comment: I don't realy understand what your goal here is.
Also, why are you changing id? I can't think of any reason to change id - it's internal db thing, and changing it could mess some things up.

Comment: look, i'm just trying to update the value of v_id from driver table which is a foreign key column but unfortunately i'm not able to do so

Comment: Try omitting `self.id = id`. No reason to change `id`.
Then please report back :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it worked automatically after making certain changes in the relation, so never mind!
And thank you all for your responses!

Comment: Hi Ram, I have the same problem, can you please let me know the changes you made to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Alembic can’t do particularly detailed checks on your `dB.Model`s do you have to change the migration script yourself. If you’re using Flask-migrate it’ll be in a migrations/versions folder. Change this using the alembic syntax found elsewhere in the file to change a foreign key.

Comment: i don't wanna migrate anything, all i want is to simply update the foreign key value!

Comment: What are you using to apply changes to database schema?